# How to use inheritance in a more complex type in Julia

Tags: inheritance, julia

I am trying to use a general type `Any` in the following function:

```
function f(arr::Array{Tuple{ASCIIString, Any},1})
    arr[1]
end
```

and it works in

```
f([("a",1), ("b","x")])
```

but in

```
f([("a",1)])
```

it does not work. One'd think an `Int` is actually an `Any`, but apparently not.

How to get `f` working in this latter case? I am interested in a general solution because this problem crops up in many places in Julia and the above is just a simple example. Should I use a `Union` of all types in place of `Any` in the tuple?

Comment: Julia 0.3.* users must use older Tuple type declaration style `( .. )` instead of `Tuple{ ... }` to get the code works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type parameters in Julia are *invariant*, see http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/types/#parametric-composite-types. To get the behavior that you are after, you need to parameterise your function by a type parameter:

```
function f{T <: Tuple{ASCIIString, Any}}(arr::Array{T,1})
    arr[1]
end
```